# Replacing NA values for a variable in a dataframe with non-NA values from prior rows conditional on values of another variable

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
weird_data <- 
  data.frame("ID" = 1:8, 
             "API" = c("01-01", 
                       "01-02", 
                       "02-01", 
                       "02-02", 
                       "02-03", 
                       "03-01", 
                       "03-02", 
                       "03-03"),  
             "Final" = c("no", 
                         "yes", 
                         "no",
                         "no", 
                         "yes", 
                         "no", 
                         "no",
                         "yes"), 
             "Month" = c("May", 
                         NA, 
                         NA, 
                         "June", 
                         "July", 
                         "April", 
                         "June",
                         NA), 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
```

In the `API` column, the first number before the hyphen is the well code and the second number after the hyphen is the activity code, with larger numbers corresponding to later activities.  I only want to keep the row corresponding to the latest activity code for each well.  For some of the wells, though, the `Month` data is only recorded for earlier acvitity codes.  Thus, for each well, if the last activity code has `NA` for `Month`, I want to replace that `NA` with the `Month` from the most recent activity code that has one recorded.  Ideally, my output would look like this:

```
desired_output <- 
  data.frame("ID" = 1:8, 
             "API" = c("01-01", 
                       "01-02", 
                       "02-01", 
                       "02-02", 
                       "02-03", 
                       "03-01", 
                       "03-02", 
                       "03-03"),  
             "Final" = c("no", 
                         "yes", 
                         "no",
                         "no", 
                         "yes", 
                         "no", 
                         "no",
                         "yes"), 
             "Month" = c("May", 
                         "May", 
                         NA, 
                         "June", 
                         "July", 
                         "April", 
                         "June",
                         "June"), 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
```

The wells are in that order, and the `Final` column does reliably indicate the wells I ultimately want to keep as `yes`, if that helps.  The real data has about 8,000 rows, though, for maybe 2,800 wells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `tidyverse` packages:

```
library(tidyverse)
output <- weird_data %>%
  separate(API, into = c("well", "act"), sep = "-", remove = F) %>%
  group_by(well) %>%
  fill(Month) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-well, -act)

all.equal(output, desired_output)
#[1] TRUE
```